# Does “at the borders of” mean “out of” in this text?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, phrase-meaning

Does “at the borders of” means “out of” in this text? If not, what is its precise meaning?

> In such ways, theology became as yet marginalised, or even banned from
> the university as no longer deserving a space because of its
> ‘irrational’ assumptions. In many places in the West, by the end of
> the twentieth century theology was thus located somewhere **at the
> borders of** its secularising universities. ([Source](https://journals.sagepub.com/doi/10.1177/0953946819868092))

Comment: Theology is still in some universities, although I'm not sure where exactly this relates to (please explain) so I guess it means on the margins/fringes.

Comment: I think it means that it's still in, but just barely acceptable. So it's close to being taken out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Borders" in this sense just means "periphery" or "outer edges" (see [The Free Dictionary](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/border)). The idea is that theology is *almost* excluded from the universities, but not quite.